# How to write PHP script for proper file download?

Tags: php, http, cross-browser, cache-control

I have trouble shooting at file download problem. In Chrome, the download works fine. In Firefox, it generate some HTML headings at the end of file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE .....>
...
...
```

For some other browsers, the downloaded files miss some lines too. How do I write the script to actually make it work properly for many browser? Here is my current code:

```
private  function downloadRawFileHelper($file) {
    if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    }
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        die('File Not Found');
    }

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: text/php");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($file). "\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    $this->view = 'fileedit';
}
```

Comment: You should start realizing that this is not relevant to any specific web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting an `exit` after `readfile` , I think that would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any issue with the code. Can you try adding `exit()` or `die()` at the end of your function. Change it to:

```
private  function downloadRawFileHelper($file) {
    if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
    }
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        die('File Not Found');
    }

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: text/php");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($file). "\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    $this->view = 'fileedit';
    exit();
}
```

You are outputting the file to browser. So you need to stop script execution after that.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Before `flush()` add `ob_end_clean();` and an `exit()` after `readfile()`.  Also, you might consider using X-SendFile instead of pure PHP to send the file to the client, as that will tie up valuable resources in the case of large files.

Answer (score 0):

here's your problem:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($file). "\"");
```

try to give a name for your archivo, for example:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($file). "filename.extension\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug HTTP problems is to actually inspect the HTTP message that is sent. Today's browsers make this really easy.

If the site is public, you can try redbot.org to check the response.

Finally, you are sending tons of undefined and/or useless response header fields, such as "Content-Transfer-Encoding", or the "check" directives in Cache-Control.